# Using String.replace to replace a multi-line section of the string in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to use Rust to go through and make changes to an HTML file.  Basically, I find specific things in the code that I want replaced, then I replace it with something else using String.replace(stringToReplace, replacingString).  This has been working well until I tried to replace a multi-line section of it. For example:

index.html

```
<div id="outer">
    <h1>Some title</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

newIndex.html

```
<p>I have replaced the whole div</p>
```

No matter what I have tried, I cannot get the string to match for multiple lines.  It just simply never replaces it.  How do I go about matching on that multi-line part of the code.  I thought about doing each line individually, but I obviously can't do that because replacing `</div>` would not be good.

Below is the code I am using.  I cannot make any changes to the original code to make it easier to match.  In main.rs I am looping through Change.changes the even indices are the string to replace and the odd indices are the replacing text.

main.rs

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

mod ejs;
mod js;
mod classes;
mod controllers;
mod change;

fn main() {
    let ejs_files: Vec<change::Change> = ejs::change();
    let js_files: Vec<change::Change> = js::change();
    let class_files: Vec<change::Change> = classes::change();
    let controller_files: Vec<change::Change> = controllers::change();

    for i in 0..ejs_files.len() {
        let mut contents = match read_file(&ejs_files[i].location) {
            Ok(contents) => contents,
            Err(e) => panic!(e)
        };

        let mut j = 0;
        while j < ejs_files[i].changes.len() {
            contents = contents.replace(ejs_files[i].changes[j], ejs_files[i].changes[j+1]);
            j += 2;
        }

        match write_file(&ejs_files[i].location, contents) {
            Err(e) => panic!(e),
            _ => ()
        };
    }

    for i in 0..js_files.len() {
        let mut contents = match read_file(&js_files[i].location) {
            Ok(contents) => contents,
            Err(e) => panic!(e)
        };

        let mut j = 0;
        while j < js_files[i].changes.len() {
            contents = contents.replace(js_files[i].changes[j], js_files[i].changes[j+1]);
            j += 2;
        }

        match write_file(&js_files[i].location, contents) {
            Err(e) => panic!(e),
            _ => ()
        };
    }

    for i in 0..class_files.len() {
        let mut contents = match read_file(&class_files[i].location) {
            Ok(contents) => contents,
            Err(e) => panic!(e)
        };

        let mut j = 0;
        while j < class_files[i].changes.len() {
            contents = contents.replace(class_files[i].changes[j], class_files[i].changes[j+1]);
            j +=2;
        }

        match write_file(&class_files[i].location, contents) {
            Err(e) => panic!(e),
            _ => ()
        };
    }

    for i in 0..controller_files.len() {
        let mut contents = match read_file(&controller_files[i].location) {
            Ok(contents) => contents,
            Err(e) => panic!(e)
        };

        let mut j = 0;
        while j < controller_files[i].changes.len() {
            contents = contents.replace(controller_files[i].changes[j], controller_files[i].changes[j+1]);
            j +=2;
        }

        match write_file(&controller_files[i].location, contents) {
            Err(e) => panic!(e),
            _ => ()
        };
    }
}

fn read_file(file: &str) -> std::io::Result<String> {
    let mut file = File::open(file)?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
    Ok(contents)
}

fn write_file(file: &str, contents: String) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = File::create(file)?;
    file.write(contents.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}
```

change.rs

```
pub struct Change<'a> {
    pub location: String,
    pub changes: Vec<&'a str>
}
```

js.rs (short example):

```
use crate::change::Change;

pub fn change<'a>() -> Vec<Change<'a>> {
    let folder_location: &str = "../../javascript/InventoryManagement/";

    let home_js = Change {
        location: format!("{}{}", folder_location, "views/dashboardPage/js/strands/home.js"),
        changes: vec![
            "% vs last month", "% по сравнению с прошлым месяцем",
            "REVENUE", "ДОХОД",
            "\"DATE\"", "\"ДАТА\"",
            "MOST POPULAR INGREDIENTS", "САМЫЕ ПОПУЛЯРНЫЕ ИНГРЕДИЕНТЫ",
            "QUANTITY", "КОЛИЧЕСТВО"
        ]
    };
```

In main.rs I am going through different files and replacing certain things.  JS, HTML(EJS) and eventually CSS.  Making the changes works well until I have to make a multi-line change.  If I do something like this then it doesn't work.

js.rs (multi-line):

```
use crate::change::Change;

pub fn change<'a>() -> Vec<Change<'a>> {
    let folder_location: &str = "../../javascript/InventoryManagement/";

    let home_js = Change {
        location: format!("{}{}", folder_location, "views/dashboardPage/js/strands/home.js"),
        changes: vec![
            "<div id='something'>
                <p>My multi-line comment</p>
           </div>", 
           "<p>Something else</p>"
        ]
    };
    vec![home_js]
}
```

If there is a better way to do this, then I would love to know as well.  Or just a way to find and replace multi-line parts of the code.  I am pretty new to Rust and this is the first project I have done with it.

Comment: Could it be that you need to add \n characters?

Comment: I tried that as well but it didn't work.   I added \n at the end of each line and no luck.

Comment: The spaces are also counted in multiline strings. Are those matching? Are the indentations exactly the same in the data that you want to replace?

Comment: This approach looks fragile. Have you considered using an HTML parser like html5ever instead?

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass I have not checked that.  I will check it and try it out, see if that solves my issue.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ya, seems pretty fragile to me as well.  Pretty new to rust and wasn't sure how to go about it.  I'll check out html5ever, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regex` crate and write a function. it replaces anything that matches the given text.

```
use regex::Regex;

fn replace(target: &str, replaceWith: &str, text: &str)-> Result<String, regex::Error>
  {
    let regex = Regex::new(target)?;
    Ok(regex.replace_all(text, replaceWith).to_string())
  }
```